# How to get active touch events without having a touch event in a browser environment

Tags: javascript, android, ios, dom, multi-touch

You can get other touch events from the targetTouches and touches properties of a TouchEvent. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent .

What I'd like to do is get a list of all touches from anywhere (ie in an event handler that is *not* for a touch event). Is this possible? How would I do that? Bonus points if you can tell me how to get the list of targetTouches active on an element.

Answer (score 0):

[See Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

You can use

> yourView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain);

Comment: So that's cool, but its also android specific. I'm looking for a way to get this info from a browser dom.